# Regular expression check for special character or number

Tags: regex

I have such regular expression which checked for `at least one special character` in the string:

```
^(.*[^0-9a-zA-Z].*)$
```

But how could i change this one to check for `at least one special character` or `at leas one number` in the string?

Comment: give examples of passing and failing input

Answer (score 2):

```
.*[^a-zA-Z]+.*
```

would match anything followed by a special character followed by anything.

Notice that I just removed the `0-9` from the *character class* (characters included in the square brackets).

Also, I removed the `^` and `$` markers -- those match the beginning and end of string respectively. You don't need it because you're making it redundant with the `.*` (match zero or more of any character) anyway.

In fact, if you're just **checking** if the string contains a special character, then the following is good enough:

```
[^a-zA-Z]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use the Expresso, it is a smart tool for generate RegExps [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/ExpressoDownload.htm)