# javascript regex to allow at least one special character and one numeric

Tags: javascript, regex

Im beginer about regex...I need to create a regular expression to check if a string has got at least one special character and one numeric. Im using `([0-9]+[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-.:;_-]+|[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-.:;_-]+[0-9]+)`, but is not working. Help please.

Comment: can u post your code which is not working....a jsfiddle would be good..

Comment: In what way is it not working? Errors? Not doing what you think it should? Actual output vs expected output would be helpful

Comment: Check this link
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102582/regular-expression-check-for-special-character-or-number

Comment: No matter the order, for example: aA*8 or 8p:

Answer (score 2):

One simple way to check is to do 2 tests on the input string for the existence of each type of character:

```
/[0-9]/.test(inputString) && /[special_characters]/.test(inputString)
```

The code will do as you described: check if there is at least 1 digit, and at least 1 special character in the `inputString`. There is no limit on the rest of the `inputString`, though.

Fill in `special_characters` with your list of special characters. In your case, it would be:

```
/[0-9]/.test(inputString) && /[!@#$%^&*(){}[\]<>?/|.:;_-]/.test(inputString)
```

I removed a few redundant escapes in your pattern for special character. (`^` doesn't need escaping, and `-` is already there at the end).

This make the code readable and less maintenance headache, compared to trying to write a single regex that do the same work.

Answer (score 1):

try this regex expression

```
(.*[0-9]+[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-]+|.*[!@#$%\^&*(){}[\]<>?/|\-]+[0-9]+)
```

Answer (score 0):

If, by *special characters*, you mean all ASCII printable symbols and punctuation that can be matched with `` [!-\/:-@[-`{-~] `` pattern (see [Check for special characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311081), you may find more special character patterns there), you may use

```
/^(?=.*?\d)(?=.*?[!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/
```

Or, taking into account the [contrast principle](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast):

```
/^(?=\D*\d)(?=[^!-\/:-@[-`{-~]*[!-\/:-@[-`{-~])/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Piak5J/1) (I added `.*` at the end and `\n` to the negated character classes in the demo because the regex is tested against a single multiline string there, you do not need them in the regex testing method in the code).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.*?\d)` - there must be at least one digit after any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=\D*\d)` - there must be at least one digit after any 0 or more characters other than a digit
- `(?=.*?[!-\/:-@[-`{-~])` - there must be at least one printable ASCII punctuation/symbol after any 0 or more characters other than line break chars, as few as possible
- `(?=[^!-\/:-@[-`{-~]*[!-/:-@[-`{-~])` - there must be at least one printable ASCII punctuation/symbol after any 0 or more characters other than a printable ASCII punctuation/symbol.