# JavaScript regex for underscore not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I used other questions but so far only stumped.

This doesn't remove underscore.

Where is the mistake

```
var myString = str.toLowerCase().replace(/\W+/
 myString= myString.replace('/\_/g','');
```

Comment: Your first line seems to have gotten cut off.

Comment: It probably does not remove the underscore because the second line never executes, because the first line will result in a syntax error. Take a look at the console.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, you can **remove all underscores from a string** using

```js
const myString = '_123__abc___-Some-Text_';
console.log(myString.replace(/_/g, ''));
console.log(myString.replaceAll('_', ''));
```

*However*, in this question, it makes sense to combine `/_/g` and `/\W+/g` regexps into one `/[\W_]+/g`. The `\W` pattern matches any char other than ASCII letters, digits *and* `_`, thus we need a custom character class to match both patterns.

Use

```
var myString = str.toLowerCase().replace(/[\W_]+/g,'');
```

where `[\W_]+` matches one or more chars other than word chars *and* a `_`.

See the [online regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nxh3qI/1).

Comment: It matches other non letter symbols also

Comment: @AlexeyBaguk Whatever you mean by "non letter symbols" is unclear. The current OP problem is removing all occurrences of substrings that match `\W` and `_` patterns, hence *for the current question*, `.replace(/[\W_]+/g, '')` is the appropriate answer. If you need a regex for special chars, see [Check for special characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970). If you need anything else, please provide more concrete details (a test case, fiddle, codepen, etc.) and state what behavior you seek.