# Regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to build a regular expression in js and for some reason I can't enter the underscore character, although all the other special characters can be entered. Here is my expression:

^[А-ЯЁа-я\w\d]*$

Expected result: Абвг_#$

Can you please tell me why this happens and how to fix it?

Comment: I guess the issue is not with underscore here, it would be with $. Because it is a token in regular expression to match end of the string. You would need to update expression like this `^[А-ЯЁа-я\w\d]*\$`. And # is not included with expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try `\W` that matches any non-ASCII char. You can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42042770/javascript-regex-for-underscore-not-working).