# get indexes of all the special characters from string

Tags: jquery

I have a string like this `"aadsa&ss))as(d?"`, i want to get index of all the special characters from it. I have tried following and getting the values, but i am sure there will be some better way of doing this.

```
  var str = "aadsa&ss))as(d?";
  var indexes = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {

   if (str[i] === "&" || str[i] === "*" || str[i] === "(" || str[i] === ")" || str[i] === ">" || str[i] === "<" || str[i] === "?") {
         indexes.push(i);
   }

}
```

Comment: What are you intending to do after you get all the indexes?

Comment: [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311081/check-for-special-characters-in-string)

Comment: quite a long process, after getting index of special characters i want to replace those characters based on two condition, if they are between alphabets then replace by - , and if they are between numbers then simply remove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be achieved by `RegExp`.

First, I replced all spaces (if any) with `'i'` as it is not a special character, and then I have used `/\W/` to search all *special characters* using [`String.search()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search).

Then, in the while loop while i searched for *special characters* I used [`String.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) to replace those *special characters* with `'i'` again, so that they couldn't be found again.

```js
var str = "aadsa&ss))as(d?";
var cpy = str;
var indexes = [];
cpy = cpy.replace(/\s+/g, 'i');
while(/\W/.test(cpy)) {
  indexes.push( cpy.search(/\W/) );
  cpy = cpy.replace(/\W/, 'i');
}

console.log(indexes);
```

Comment: it gave output as "5,7,7,9,10" but correct answer should be "5,8,9,12,14"...isn't it?

Comment: I was about to say too. Look at my output it should be correct.

Answer (score 1):

As shown before you should probably do it via regex but here still the answer to your question:

```js
let str = "aadsa&ss))as(d?";
let specialChars = ["(", ")", "&", "?"];
let indexes = [];

for(let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  if(specialChars.indexOf(str[i]) != -1) indexes.push(i);
}

console.log(indexes);
```

You can of course put all the characters you like into the array :)