# How to restrict white-space at only begin?

Tags: regex

I have written the regex pattern for restricting white space at the start but it is not working. Guide me in finding where I need to change the logic?

```
^[^\s]+[a-z-A-Z]$
```

I need to do this in java-script to validate the input field. I need to allow all character in the input field without white space at start and I need all white space at the end and intermediate.

Comment: `[^\s]` means not (`^`) a whitespace character (`\s`).

Comment: It's not really clear what you want. Could you give some sample strings that match and some that don't.

Comment: i need to allow all character in the input field without white space at start. i need to all white space at intermediate and end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `[^\s]` matches *any* char but a whitespace while you want to allow only letters and spaces.

Use

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*$
```

NOTE: to also "allow" (=match) any printable ASCII chars other than space, letters and digits you may add `[!-\/:-@[-`{-~]` to the regex (please refer to [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970)):

```
^[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s!-\/:-@[-`{-~]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NNSj04/1) and a [regex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E%5Ba-zA-Z%5D%5Ba-zA-Z%5Cs%5D*%24):

[image]

Or, if an empty string should be matched, too:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z\s]*)?$
```

Note that to include a hyphen to the character class, it is much safer (and more portable) to place it at the start/end of the character class, i.e. use `[a-zA-Z-]` instead of `[a-z-A-Z]`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of a string
- `[a-zA-Z]` - an ASCII letter
- `[a-zA-Z\s]*` - 0 or more ASCII letters or whitespaces
- `$` - end of string.

`(?:...)?`  is an optional non-capturing group that matches its pattern 1 or 0 times.

Comment: need to allow spacial character also.

Comment: @Manikandan What chars are special for you? Please check [this anwer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970) and I think you will be able to adjust this regex on your own. Else, add more details to the question

Comment: thanks i have tried your pattern it is working i have added my special character in my pattern ^[a-zA-Z0-9][a-zA-Z!@#$%^&*?(){}\s]*$