# Number or special character requirement addition to password validation regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to validate password with: At least one uppercase, at least one lowercase, at least one **number OR symbol**, at least 8 characters.

I have this regex:

```
/^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9]).{8,20}$/
```

This works fine except of > it checks string on **number AND symbol**, but not on **number OR symbol**. And also character length 8-20, not at least 8 but gives range. I want it to check **number OR symbol**. Any ideas? Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but for those thinking of validating passwords themselves I can highly recommend https://github.com/dropbox/zxcvbn instead.

Comment: Remove `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` and replace `(?=.*\d)` with `(?=.*(?:\d|[^\w\s]))`

Comment: Also, [what chars do you consider "special"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks. Post your answer not comment. I will approve and upvote it. Have a good day

Comment: So  a space is a special char, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew well it is I think. But not in my case

Comment: But `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` matches a space, and hence `[\W\d_]`, too, matches a space and it will be counted as special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(?=.*\d)` positive lookahead requires a digit in the string AND `(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])` requires a char other than ASCII letter or digit.

To make the regex require a digit OR a char other than ASCII letter or digit, merge the two lookaheads as

```
(?=.*[^A-Za-z])
```

Basically, you need to remove `0-9` from the second lookahead and it will require any char but an ASCII letter.

Result:

```
/^(?=.*[^A-Za-z])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,20}$/
```

Or, a much more efficient version based on the [contrast principle](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-style.html#contrast):

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z]*[^A-Za-z])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,20}$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lvmlXi/2).

If a space is not special, add it  to the lookahead:

```
/^(?=[A-Za-z ]*[^A-Za-z ])(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z]).{8,20}$/
            ^          ^
```