# Deny string with special characters only

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that is working fine:

```
^(?!\\d+$)\\S{8,}$
```

- `(?!d+$)` // Deny numbers only
- `\S{8,}` // Allow special characters but white spaces and a minimum of 8 characters;

But I need to add one more thing: Deny if the string is special characters only.

tried to apply the same logic as the "only numbers deny", an add

```
(?!\\S+$))
```

to the existing regex, but didn't work as expected.

obs: I will work with different languages, so the "special characters" would be:

`! @ # $ % & * ( ) _ - = < > , . ? } ] { [ +`

Comment: Which characters do you consider "special"? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970. Then just use the right set in the negative lookahead.

Comment: Would love an explanation for the downvote, so I can improve next time.  @WiktorStribiżew  I edited the questions with more info.

Comment: **Duplicate of [Check for special characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32311188/3832970)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Deny if the string is special characters only.

For this add another negative lookahead assertion:

```
^(?!\\d+$)(?![-!@#$%&*()_=<>,.;]+$)\\S{8,}$
```

`(?![-!@#$%&*()_=<>,.;]+$)` is negative lookahead to fail the match if input contains only those listed characters.

Comment: `\W` matches `ż`, it is not special, it is just a letter.

Comment: Hi! as I will work with multiple languages I believe I only need to deny speicla characters like: `!@#$%&*()-_=<>,.;`. But they are acceptable as long as there is number and/or letters together. Only need to deny special characters only.

Comment: OP thought `\S` matches special characters. `\W` is going to confuse OP even more. @PlayHardGoPro, just do what I suggested in the comment. Your strategy is good, all you need to find out is the right set of chars you consider special.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @PlayHardGoPro. I have updated answer accordingly.

Comment: @anubhava Please do not re-open duplicate questions. Please consider re-closing.

Comment: That wasn't an exact dupe