# Handling special characters in Java script to enclose them in Square Brackets?

Tags: javascript, regex, special-characters

I am trying to write a Java Script function that should enclose all the special characters in the given String in a bracket like following -

`Input   ===> Output`

`123@#$, ====> 123[@][#][$][,]`

Changing All the special characters to certain String [ _ in this case]  is easy -

`string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'_');`

Comment: `.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/g,'[$&]')`. You may find some more advanced [special char regexps here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311081/check-for-special-characters-in-string/32311188#32311188).

Comment: What about non-latin characters? Does é count as "special"?