# Regex password validation not working - javascript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, regex, security

I have the javascript below. I am trying to put in place password validation rules to have the following:

- At least 12 characters long (works)
- At least 1 letter (works)
- At least 1 uppercase letter (doesn't work)
- At least 1 digit (works)
- At least 1 special character (doesn't work)

Could I please get pointers on how to get the uppercase & special characters validations to work?

```
// Register Handle
router.post('/register', (req, res) => {
    const { name, email, password, password2, userType } = req.body;

    let errors = [];

    // Check required fields
    if(!name || !email || !password || !password2 || !userType){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Please fill in all fields'})
    }

    // Check if passwords match
    if(password !== password2) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Passwords do not match' });
    }

    // Check password length
    if(password.length < 12) {
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should be at least 12 characters long' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 letter
    if(password.search(/[a-z]/i) < 0){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one letter' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 Uppercase letter
    if(password.search(/[A-Z]/i) < 0){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one uppercase character' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 number
    if(password.search(/[0-9]/) < 0){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one number' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 special character
    if(password.search() < 0){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one number' });
    }

    if(errors.length > 0) {
        res.render('register', {
            errors,
            name,
            email,
            password,
            password2,
            userType
        })
    } else {
        // Passed Validation
        User.findOne({ email: email })
            .then(user => {
                if(user) {
                    // User exists
                    errors.push({ msg: 'Email already registered' });
                    res.render('register', {
                        errors,
                        name,
                        email,
                        password,
                        password2,
                        userType
                    })
                } else {
                    const newUser = new User({
                        name,
                        email,
                        password,
                        userType
                    });

                    // Hash Password
                    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => bcrypt.hash(newUser.password, salt, (err, hash) =>{
                        if(err) throw err;
                        // Sets password to hash
                        newUser.password = hash;

                        // Save user
                        newUser.save()
                            .then(user => {
                                req.flash('success_msg', 'Registration successful! Login to continue')
                                res.redirect('/auth/login')
                                return;
                            })
                            .catch(err => console.log(err));
                    }))
                }
            })
    }
});
```

Comment: Remove the `i` flag from the letter checks. It makes the regexp case-insensitive, which doesn't make sense, when you're specifically checking the case.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Do you know how I can put in a validation for special characters?

Comment: `/\W/` matches any non-alphanumeric character. You might also benefit [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/632aqskf/1/), I made it for another a bit similar question.

Answer (score 2):

Letter and digit checks should be updated as follows:

```js
    // Check if password contains at least 1 letter
    if(/[a-z]/i.test(password)){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one letter' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 Uppercase letter
    if(/[A-Z]/.test(password)){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one uppercase character' });
    }

    // Check if password contains at least 1 number
    if(/[0-9]/.test(password)){
        errors.push({ msg: 'Password should contain at least one number' });
    }
```

Better use `test` instead of `search` when checking if an expression can match anything in the string, and `/[A-Z]/i` matches any letters case-insensitively.

P.S. If you want to check special characters see [Check for special characters in string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311081/check-for-special-characters-in-string). There are heaps of ways to match special characters in JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you! One question - Why is it better to use 'test' instead of 'search'?

Comment: @Jay `test` returns a boolean straight away.