# how to search and replace Single Quotes in a String in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

Hello i need help Searching a Text String for Special Characters

Something like this e.g

```
const str = "am trying to find a string's Special Character's now";
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32311081/check-for-special-characters-in-string

Comment: You cannot nest quotes. This is an invalid JS string: `" am trying to find a string's Special Character's "here" now"`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=search+and+replace+Single+Quotes+String+JavaScript+site:stackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: @mplungan  sorry i have edited it's now remaining  with single quote.